# Mass Dimension of derivative in a Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dimensional-analysis, action

What is the mass dimension of the derivative $\partial$ in a Lagrangian? I am really confused about this. I read somewhere it is 1 and another place I saw it is -1.

Please could someone clear this confusion? You can consider any Lagrangian in Quantum Field theory as an illustration.

Comment: It is unclear what you  are asking. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We work in units wherein $c = \hbar = 1$. Recall the Compton wavelength is,

$$\lambda = \frac{\hbar}{mc}$$

and thus in our units length scales $\lambda$ have units of inverse mass or equivalently inverse energy, and so we say $[\lambda] = -1$, i.e. $[\lambda] = [M]^{-1}$. The partial differential is,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$$

which has the dimensions of the inverse of length, so $[\partial] =1$. This derivation is independent of the notion of a Lagrangian. We can now apply this knowledge to say, scalar field theory:

$$\mathcal L = \frac12 \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi, \quad S = \int \mathcal L \, \mathrm d^4x.$$

The action has the same units as $\hbar$ which is set to one, so $[S] = 0$. Each $\mathrm dx$ has units of length, and so $[\mathrm d^4x] = -4$ from which we find $[\mathcal L] = 4$. Knowing $[\partial] = 1$, we find $[\phi] = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Cleared quite a bit of confusion. I was confused between the partial and the normal derivative which, I think you explained it quite well.